# How to check if array contains instance of an object in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have an object like this:

```
MyLibrary {
  books: 
   [ Book {
      bookType: 'romance'
     } 
  ]
}
```

Book is a class.

I would like to write a test to check if books contain an object that is an instance of Book. I was expecting to use something like MyLibrary.books.indexOf('Book') but it returns -1 even when Book exist.

Comment: You want to check whether [`.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) elements in `books` are an [`instanceof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof) `Book`…

Comment: wow.. -2 already just because I didn't know about .some and instanceof. It worked @deceze thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You literally have [`instanceof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof):

```
var hasBook = books.some((book) => book instanceof Book);
```